# How do I upgrade to gradle 7.* when using mingc/android-build-box?

Tags: android, docker, bitbucket

I have been using BitBucket pipelines for sometime now and suddenly from yesterday builds have been failing with the following error

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
You can try some of the following options:
- changing the IDE settings.
- changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
- changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

I am using Gradle version 7 / java 1.8 in my local machine builds and I am able to get the build done successfully. Not certain what is going wrong on the server builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitbucket pipeline for Android relies on [mingc/android-build-box](https://hub.docker.com/r/mingc/android-build-box/) which of (today) uses Java 1.8 as default. Solve the problem by setting `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` environment variables as first steps in your `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```
pipelines:
  default:
      - step:

          [...]

          script:
            - export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin:$PATH
            - export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/

          [...]
```